# Position view relative to another view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label whose bottom I'm trying to anchor to the bottom of my custom nav bar (navBar). I'm trying to use this code:

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, navBar.bounds.minY, 200, 21))
label.center = self.view.center
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "I'm a test label"
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

But `navBar.bounds.minY` isn't the right call. Is this something I'd set within `CGRectMake` or should I be using a `label.bounds` method??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you get help from this

```
    var labelwidth : Int = 200
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-(labelwidth/2), navBar.frame.origin.y+navBar.frame.size.height, labelwidth, 21))
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.text = "I'm a test label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)
```

As per my understanding, you want the label below the `navBar`. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Setting the frame of the label with `CGRectMake` isn't making a difference anywhere. May be because of `label.center = self.view.center`. But the label is docked at center.x and center.y for me. I want the bottom of the label at the bottom of the nav bar.

Comment: if you want to make the label to center of screen on top then `CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-100, navBar.frame.origin.y+navBar.frame.size.height, 200, 21))` because view.center means center of the screen. @dperk

Comment: Yes, thank you. Why do we subtract 100 from `self.view.frame.size.width/2`, out of curiosity? Will that hold for all screen sizes?

Comment: @dperk 100 is your label width divided by 2 :)

Comment: @dperk updated answer. it will work for all screen size